# Single-click to open an item (point to select)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Some users actually prefer to open/execute files on a single click and have configured their windows accordingly.

I need to access this information so i can mimic the behaviour in a custom ListBoxControl. However I havent got a clue where this setting could be stored.

Probably my english isnt good enough to search for the right term here. I suspect this to be accessable by wmi.

Comment: Are you asking that you want the user to click on an item in a ListBoxControl and take that as a sign to close the control and pull the data following (i.e. ListBox_OnClickEvent)?

Comment: I think they're asking how to read the `Single-click to open an item (point to select)` option from the **Folder Options->General**

Comment: Answer at bottom here may be of use : http://www.overclock.net/t/1418289/issue-with-double-click-to-open - though I have seen comments this may not work with all versions of Windows

Comment: @JamesBarrass Correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This value is stored in the registry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellState` at fifth byte.

You can check if single click is set with this:

```
var value = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\", "ShellState", null) as byte[];
var singleClick = value != null && (value[4] & 32) == 0;
```

Comment: Damn how could i forget about the registry. I will try it out tomorrow and mark this answer accepted if it works.